# iOS browsers (Chrome/Safari) scroll flickering due to video

Tags: html, css, html5-video, mobile-safari

In mobile safari, I'm noticing screen flickering whenever I hit the edge of a scrollable area that contains an HTML5 video. In addition, scrolling seems to flicker at various other moments.

I have a codepen replicating this issue here - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZxabYR

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="item-content">
  <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/storyforj/image/upload/c_limit,w_1500,f_auto,fl_lossy.preserve_transparency.progressive,q_auto/ugc/3Y7A8506_izkrbg">
  <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/storyforj/image/upload/c_limit,w_1500,f_auto,fl_lossy.preserve_transparency.progressive,q_auto/ugc/3Y7A8506_izkrbg">
  <video controls loop autoplay controlslist="nodownload" playsinline>
    <source src="https://res.cloudinary.com/storyforj/video/upload/c_limit,w_1500,f_auto,fl_lossy,q_auto/ugc/Chop1_compressed_i4x9gt.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="https://res.cloudinary.com/storyforj/video/upload/c_limit,w_1500,f_auto,fl_lossy,q_auto/ugc/Chop1_compressed_i4x9gt.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="https://res.cloudinary.com/storyforj/video/upload/c_limit,w_1500,f_auto,fl_lossy,q_auto/ugc/Chop1_compressed_i4x9gt.ogv" type="video/ogg"> 
  </video>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.item-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Things I've tried:
 1. Trying to hardware accelerate using translate: transform3d and
    perspective.
 2. Trying to disable the elastic band effect when you hit the edge of the screen (I was not successful at this - is it not possible any
    more).

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So I filled a bug against webkit - https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=184025

One interim solution is to replace the video player with a canvas based video player - here's a demo https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JLOGWE. There is a whole bunch of code here, but by using this https://github.com/Stanko/html-canvas-video-player example you can initialize an canvas video like so:

```
var canvasVideo = new CanvasVideoPlayer({
    videoSelector: '.js-video',
    canvasSelector: '.js-canvas'
});
canvasVideo.play();
```

This of course has its own problems, and requires re-implementation of some basic functionality that the normal video player has. None the less, it appears to be quite stable on iOS.